# Delphi structure definition

Tags: delphi, pascal

I came across this structure definition in Delphi. I am very new to Delphi. I am going through my Delphi trying to make head or tail out of this code below. I can't seem to figure out what exactly this means. It would be great if someone could explain.

```
// MSG
  TPayloadHdr = packed record
    Count: byte;
  end;
  PPayload = ^Payload;
  Payload = packed record
    Hdr: TPayloadHdr;
    TagLen: packed array[0..MAXINT div (2*sizeof(word))] of word;
    // Data: array[0..] of byte;  Use @TagLen[Hdr.Count] to get a pointer to the first structure.  
    function GetSize: integer;
  end;
```

The questions that I have.

1. Why are there two `end` without `begin`
2. What does `^Payload` mean?
3. Is `record` a keyword ? What does it mean?

Comment: I think you mean "begin" rather than "start" and "record" rather than "rec".  Anyway, Pascal grammar uses "end" in a variety of contexts, not just in "begin - end" pairs, e.g. to signal the end of a record definition or a class definition.  "^Something" means "pointer to Something"

Comment: @MartynA - Is that a record defintion in the above example?

Comment: Actually, there are two in your example, of TPayloadHdr and Payload.  A Record is like a Struct in C.

Comment: @liv2hak: Yes. The code in your example follows a `type` keyword.

Comment: This is all documented

Comment: All 3 of these questions could have been answered using any basic introduction tutorial to Delphi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [The syntax for defining a record](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Structured_Types#Records_.28traditional.29) contains an `end` without a `begin`.
2. If `Something` is a type, then `^Something` is also a type, namely, a [pointer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_%28Delphi%29#Pointer_Types) to `Something`.
3. `record` is a keyword used to define [record types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Structured_Types#Records_.28traditional.29).

Comment: what does  `packed array[0..MAXINT div (2*sizeof(word))] of word;` mean?

Comment: It is a type. It is an [array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Structured_Types#Arrays) of [words](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Delphi_Data_Types#Integer_Data_Types) (16-bit unsigned integers); the indices range from `0` to `MAXINT div (2*sizeof(word))`, so there are `MAXINT div (2*sizeof(word)) + 1` elements. `MAXINT` is the largest 32-bit signed integer value (2^31 - 1 = 2147483647), `sizeof(word) = 2` (because 16 bits is 2 bytes). The array is [packed](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Structured_Types#Alignment_of_Structured_Types).

Comment: @liv2hak This is a trick to define a big static array, so that no overflow may appear. There is no such array allocated, but just a pointer to a memory buffer of words. Then the data structure itself starts after the words, i.e. at @TagLen[Hdr.Count] - here @ means "at", i.e. it returns a pointer to the first structure item.

Comment: @Andreas packed is ignored in arrays in delphi

Comment: @David: thought so too, but was a bit confused by the documentation which implies otherwise: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Structured_Types#Alignment_of_Structured_Types

Comment: The documentation is odd. `packed` only has meaning in Delphi for records and classes, and presumably objects.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Pardon my curiousity but odd in what respect?  Surely, "packed" dates from the era when it was a commonplace for (TP) databases to consist of datafiles which were "file of xxxRecordType", and where the "packed" was required to ensure that the memory image was the same as for the file's records?

Comment: @MartynA In Delphi `packed array` and `array` are interchangeable